# Mock the response of a webservice using Spring 3.2 and Mockito

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, integration-testing, mockito

In the application that I'm working, we have to consume some data from a webservice, process it, and then send it to the frontend. Now I'm trying to write an integration test that have to check the correctness of the values sent to the frontend.

I was able to load the application context doing:

```
@Inject
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
        .addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build();
}
```

After that, if I do something like:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/url"))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
```

It works very well and I get the same response that the one made from the browser.

To consume the data from the other API, I use `RestTemplate.getForObjetct` method. Therefore, I wonder if there is a way to intercept the call to this method and mock the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a couple of new classes - `RestTemplateWrapper` and `RestTemplateWrapperFactory`.  The former should have a `RestTemplate` inside, and just expose those parts of `RestTemplate` that you want to interact with, including `getForObject`.  To instantiate `RestTemplateWrapper`, you'll use a `RestTemplateWrapperFactory`.

Now, any class that creates `RestTemplate` objects should be refactored to allow for the injection of a `RestTemplateWrapperFactory`, and to interact only with the `RestTemplateWrapper` objects that it creates.

When it comes time to test, you'll use a mocking framework such as Mockito or EasyMock to create a mock `RestTemplateWrapperFactory`, and stub it so that it creates mocks of `RestTemplateWrapper`, with whatever behaviour you want for `getForObject`.  Then inject your mock `RestTemplateWrapperFactory` into whichever class you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to achieve what you want by providing a `@Mock` of `RestTemplate` using the Mockito `@InjectMocks` annotation on your service instance without having to use any wrappers around `RestTemplate`.

So I would propose that your Test class looks something like the following:

```
@Inject
private WebApplicationContext wac;

/* Inject your service implementation from your Spring ApplicationContext*/
@InjectMocks
@Inject
private MyService myService;

/* This Mock RestTemplate will be injected into your service instance by Mockito */
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() throws Exception
{
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
    .addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build();
}
```

What is actually happening here:

1. You build your ApplicationContext as normal
2. You inject a reference to your service implementation from the ApplicationContext into your test
3. You use the `@Mock` implementation from Mockito to create a Mock `RestTemplate` instance in the context of your test
4. Placing the `@InjectMocks` annotation onto your MyService implementation says to Mockito "Where possible inject Mocks into this instance"
5. Mockito injects the Mock `RestTemplate` into your service instance

You can then go ahead and write your test as normal and then use Mockito to mock operations of the `RestTemplate` and to verify them e.g.

```
@Test
public void testServiceUsesRestTemplateProperly()
{
     Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com", String.class)).thenReturn("hello world");

    String s = myService.doSomething();
    Assert.assertEquals("hello world", s);

    Mockito.verify(restTemplate).getForObject("http://example.com", String.class);
}
```

(Apologies if I'm mixing jUnit syntax in here)

Further information worth reading:

1. [InjectMocks documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, finally I was able to inject the restTemplate, but no using @InjectMock. What I've done is define a `mockedRestTemplate` and inject it by the constructor of the RestRepository